# How does memory management system of Objective C effects C++ objects embedded in interfaces of Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Another Query :
If am declaring an C++ object inside interface of Objective C. and this C++ object is not a pointer.How is it managed and destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not a pointer, then the C++ object will form part of the Objective-C object itself. So if the C++ object is 12 bytes then when you alloc the Objective-C object, 12 bytes of that object are reserved for the C++ object. So, whenever the Objective-C object is deallocated, those bytes that the C++ object is held in are destroyed along with the Objective-C object.

It's no different to have any instance variables in an Objective-C object.